# Closing JAppletFrame without closing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have placed a button on my parent JFrame which on click opens a JAppletFrame, now when i close the JAppletFrame the whole application closes. So is there any method that only my child frame closes and not the parent frame?Here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    applet = new HearDAHDSR();


    //User defined class containing the frames
    window = new window1();
    //window2 window = new window2();
    //then you set to your node
    frame = window.frame();
    frame.setSize(700, 500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //User defined class containing all panels
    panel = new Panels();

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    //Retrieving the width and height of the frame
    w = frame.getContentPane().getWidth();
    h = frame.getContentPane().getHeight();

    //
    JPanel bar_panel = panel.Bar();
    JPanel tabbed_playlist = panel.Playlist(w,h);

    frame.getContentPane().add(bar_panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Adding the Playlist and Library tabs
    tabbedPane.addTab("Playlist", tabbed_playlist);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Library", panel.Library(w,h));

    launch(args);;
}


}
public static void effect2(){
    frame2 = new JAppletFrame( "Effect", applet );
    frame2.setSize( 440, 300 );
    frame2.setVisible( true );
    frame2.test();
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame2.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame2.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Don't use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. Instead use:

```
frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame2.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

If the applet frame is the only frame, then the JVM will exit, but if more than one frame is open the other frame will remain open.

Comment: yeah tried that too but not working...even tried HIDE_ON_CLOSE but no luck

Comment: Try posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & either include the `JAppletFrame` code or at least link to the Java Docs for it.  I've never heard of that class..